# How do I create and store data in a user's profile from a Facebook Messenger Dialogflow Bot using verified details from Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, chatbot, google-authentication, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a bot using Dialogflow which is connected to Facebook Messenger. Both Messenger based Chatfuel and Dialogflow use Facebook Authentication Intent and Google Sign-In respectively.

However, I could not find a way to fetch verified user details from Facebook and store them as standalone profiles and authenticate them automatically when users log back into Facebook and start a new chat.

My purpose is to:

- Fetch Verified Details from Facebook Profile (Name, E-mail and Date of Birth)
- Use Google Authentication to Verify Phone Number and Generate Unique UserID
- Store above details along with a few other rows of data. (Still not sure where and how to store)
- Fetch the above details when the user starts a new chat on Facebook Messenger after a Google OTP Authentication.

Comment: Can you explain how you are integrating chatfuel and dialogflow? Also, to understand better your scenario, do you want each user  to sign in using both authentication methods (facebook log in, google sign in)? In general, if you can provide a diagram or an example of the authentication flow you want each user to follow (for the first time, and for subsequent) it would be great

Comment: I was planning to use either Dialogflow or Chatfuel. The end-user platform will be Facebook Messenger. For users using the bot for the first time, they will need to verify the phone number using any authentication method (you suggest!).

Comment: Once signed in, the authentication token will be generated against the user which will be valid for 30 days (or a specific duration). The user will be automatically signed in on the basis of his Facebook profile each time he starts a new conversation and all his details (such as bookings) will be fetched from Firebase.

Comment: authentication flow (maybe Noob like) Download PDF from this [link](https://tg-go.noyes.in/i/BQACAgUAAxkBA-q1-V5XHgjRCY0s0ChJUhkw-dOHrDjgAAIxAQACtl64Vn0AAQW3RiiSexgE/2aa9cc23aba50a3ed247d884f71eab86/1582858800)